# receive/make calls on my pc via my android phone

Tags: calls, tethering

is it possible to receive / make calls on my pc via my android phone. if so how? i have been searching the internet for a while now to find a solution for this.
I have a rooted HTC Desire and i live in Denmark if that changes anything.

Comment: do you also mean by routing your PC's mic and speakers to work with the android's phone call?

Answer (score 3):

Your PC / laptop needs to connect to your phone via Bluetooth. In Windows 7, provided your phone supports the relevant Bluetooth connections, you should be able to use your computer to listen to /speak with calls received on your phone.

You need to PAIR your phone with your computer via Bluetooth to enable this functionality.

In Windows 7, click the Bluetooth icon in the notification area (system tray) and choose your device.

Comment: and..? so the mic and speakers of the headphone automatically connect to the android after that?

Comment: I believe so. Depends on your device and bluetooth stack. Try and see. :-)

Comment: That's weird.. my generic laptop built in bluetooth on windows 7 shows my android device (paired) but it greys out.. (should I open a new question)?