# How to use my mac as a bluetooth headset?

Tags: calls, tethering

My phone and the mac is already paired. What do i need to do next? I can't seem to find anything on the internet. I think the correct term would be to tether the phone call. Pretty similar to [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3908/receive-make-calls-on-my-pc-via-my-android-phone), except I'm on a mac. And my phone is not rooted. Over at System Preferences, it says that the phone is already paired. I'm on Android 2.3.4.

[image]